# IntelliJ "Generate Groovydoc" stop working

Tags: groovy, groovydoc

I used the **Tools -> Generate Groovydoc...** without any problems, but now its stopped working. If i create new projects i don't have this option.
Can i see logs somehow about the doc generation? I don't know where can i start the investigation.

```
IDEA 2016.3.4 

Build #IC-163.12024.16, built on January 31, 2017

JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

I tried to clean, rebuild my project, but not helped.
Thanks!

Comment: Please report to youtrack.jetbrains.com